# extension for keyboard show notification iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I'm using this code. if keyboard appears then it increases the size of the view so user can easily scroll to the bottom. everything works fine but I want to make an extension for this code because I don't want to use such a long code in my controller

```
import UIKit

    extension UIViewController {


        func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
            let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer =     UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:    #selector(dismissKeyboard))
            tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
            view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        }


        @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
            view.endEditing(true)
        }

        func setnotification()
        {

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        }

        @objc func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification)
        {

            var info = notification.userInfo!
            let keyboardSize = (info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
            let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardSize!.height+10, right: 0.0)
            self.scrolView.contentInset = contentInsets
            self.scrolView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
            var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
            aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
            if let activeField =  activeTextField
            {
                if (!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin))
                {
                   self.scrolView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
        // when keyboard hide reduce height of scroll view
        @objc func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification){
            let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0,bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
            myScrolView!.contentInset = contentInsets
            myScrolView!.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extensions add new functionality to an existing class, structure, enumeration, or protocol type.

Syntax for extension:

```
    extension ViewControllerName {
      // Put code which you want to 
    }      

   /**
     If you implement UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate methods 
     or you can implement for UIPickerViewDataSource methods and protocol also    
  */

   extension ViewController: UItableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

     //implement tableview datasource and delegate method 

   }

      /**
          Keyboard show/hide 
      */  
      extension ViewController {
       /**
           Add scrollview functionality to scroll top and you can call 
           this function from anywhere in the controller.
       */
       func scrollToTop() {

       } 


        @objc func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification)
            {
                var info = notification.userInfo!
                let keyboardSize = (info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
                let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardSize!.height+10, right: 0.0)
                self.scrolView.contentInset = contentInsets
                self.scrolView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
                var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
                aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
                if let activeField = self.activeTextField
                {
                    if (!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin))
                    {
                        self.scrolView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
                    }
                }
            }
            // when keyboard hide reduce height of scroll view
            @objc func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification){
                let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0,bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
                self.scrolView.contentInset = contentInsets
                self.scrolView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
                self.view.endEditing(true)
            }
        }
```

Comment: but i dont want to use scrolview in every viewcontroller?

Comment: Then create the function for scrollview implementation and put it in extension.

Comment: Check answer, I add a function in extension and you can call it from anywhere in view controller itself. @Shahzad

Comment: bro i want to send uiscrolview object  to extension

Comment: an extension is not a function that you can send an object, https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html you follow this tutorial then your all doubts are clear

Comment: still need solution for my problem

Comment: code updated , now i want to know how to send UIscrollview object to this extension from my controller